# Two horizontal divs' fluid height in a div

Tags: css, html, nested, height

I am not a web designer.. I'm just a asp.net programmer and I'm having a hard time with IE7.
Well I managed to work what i want in IE8, IE9, and Chrome. 
Now I have to make it work it in IE7.

First this is my source

I am using DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"

and html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="ko" xml:lang="ko"

```
<style type="text/css">
    html {
    height: 100%
}
body {
    background-color: #5c87b2;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #696969;
    border: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    height: 100%; 
    max-height: 100%;
}
</style>
```

```
<div id="header" style="
                        display:block;
                        position:fixed;
                        height:50px; width:100%;
                        background-color:red;">
                        d

</div>
<div id="menu" style="
                        display:block;
                        position:fixed;
                        width:200px;
                        top:50px; left:0; right:auto; bottom:0;
                        background-color:blue;">
                        d

</div>
<div id="button" style="
                        display:block;
                        position:fixed;
                        width:auto; height:100px;
                        top:50px; left:200px; right:0; bottom:auto;
                        background-color:Yellow;">
                        d
</div>
<div id="content" style="
                        display:block;
                        position:fixed;
                        width:auto; height:auto;
                        top:150px; left:200px; right:0; bottom:0;
                        background-color:green;">
    <div style="
                position:relative;
                height:50%;
                min-height:50%;
                border:3px solid pink;
                ">12412
    </div>
    <div style="
                position:relative;
                height:50%;
                border:3px solid white;
                ">
                2214124
    </div>
</div>
```

so I have a header(red), menu on the left side(blue), sub-header(yellow), container(green)
and i need two divs in the container(pink, white border).
they need to fill up the container 100% vertically.
All the outside divs' positions are fixed.
And I gave the inner two divs' position relative and gave 50% height to both.
It works fine in IE8,9, Chrome.

I will not use script. Only trying to use css styles.

So can u guys please give me some help??

Thank U!!!!!

Comment: what if you switch to a strict doctype? would it solve the issue?

Comment: For experimentation, here's the source: http://jsfiddle.net/developdaly/hjkZm/

Comment: @F. Calderan :( Well maybe that will work but XHTML 1.0 is the only DOC TYPE i can use

Answer (score 0):

Setting a height on the outer #content div allows the inner divs to display as in the other browsers. As you are looking for a full-screen panel set-up, I'm not sure how you could achieve this with pixel values. Changing from px to % and specifying positioning and width / heights as fluid seems to achieve the desired effect in IE7.

http://jsfiddle.net/VCztH/3/

Comment: hmm... but i do need the stuff's size to be fixed in same height.